# Cross-compiling Mono for MIPS32

Tags: gcc, mono, mips, mips32

I am trying to cross compile mono on SetTopBox (Linux Platform) which
has a MIPS 32-bit architecture. I have tried out different toolchains;
in every case I am able to configure mono, but when I run `make`
it gives me error. Is it because the GCC version of the toolchain does 
not have a version number higher than the GCC version for mono?

For example, if the Mono version is 3.2 and I have GCC version 4.6, what 
should be the minimum GCC version required for the tool chain that I 
will be using. Can I use a tool chain with a GCC version less than 4.6 or not?

Comment: If you are hitting a compilation error, please post the relevant part of the output from `make` in your question

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying on build on STB platform (mips32), using any tool chain won't help. You need to use SoC specific toolchain. The toolchain itself will give you the required version of GCC/G++ version based on the SoC you are  using.

Secondly, ensure that the platform PC where you are building the cross compilation has all the required system packages necessary.

Thanks!